# MS. Word : Text enter on it's own (how to connect these sentences?)

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

I'm editing citation but there are sentences separated (put) on a new line automatically instead of being just separated by a space.

[image]

How to fix this? This behaviour happens anytime there's a url in the paragraph.

Comment: The URI is a single word, so it will not fit on the line above.

Comment: Hi thanks, are there any solutions for this instead of just filling the space with more new sentences ?

Comment: A URI doesn't work if a dash is used to break it on two lines the way you may do with a multi-syllabic word. The dash could be construed as part of the URI.

Comment: you could make the font much smaller, then it'd be on the same line

Comment: I've end up adding more words like *WIkipedia : The Free Encyclopedia* :D , I've no coice to reduce the font size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually break the text of the URL into two lines at about the halfway point (or wherever looks best), and then add the full URL as a hyperlink to each of two halves. That way, no matter which half the user clicks on, he will still be able to navigate to it without any issue.

EDIT:

To get [this initial screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oii0B.jpg), I did the following:

1. Insert a line break between `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki` and `/Active_contour_model`
2. Select the `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki` text
3. Right-click the selected text, and click the `Hyperlink...` option
4. Paste the full URL into the `Address` textbox at the bottom of the `Insert Hyperlink` dialog
5. Word will automatically populate the `Text to display` textbox at the top of the dialog with the full URL you just pasted; change it back to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki`
6. Click the `OK` button

Then, perform similar steps for the `/Active_contour_model` text, which results in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcpJU.jpg), in which my mouse is hovered over the `/Active_contour_model` link.  As you can see, it is linking to the full URL.

Comment: Hi can you supply pictures, I get your description but not sure If I get it righ.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I've never had to add the hyperlink twice in this way. Just make the full URL a hyperlink, and then insert a manual line break (Shift+Enter) in the appropriate place. Each part should remain linked

Comment: That does work.  Thanks, @Chris, I hadn't thought of Shift+Enter.